# Setting the options in a drop-down menu based on the selected option of another

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu

Bellow I have two drop-down menus. One fetches the list of "Coalitions" and the other the list of "candidates" from the database. What I'm trying to do is to list the candidates in the second drop-down menu, based on the coalition selected in the first. Basically list/set the candidates that are in the same coalition in the second drop-down menu. The problem is that I'm unable to first get the selected item from the "coalition" menu and second use that value to set the second.

here is my code:

```
<form action ="includes/admin.users.inc.php" method="POST">
    <div style = "display: inline-block;">
    <!-- the coalitions -->

        <select class="form-control" id = "coalition_id" name ="coalition_select" method="POST">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Coalitions</option>
            <?php 
                include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
                $sql_coalition = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT coalition FROM candidates");
                while ($row = $sql_coalition->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value=\"\">" . $row['coalition'] . "</option>";
                }
                global $coalition_select;
                echo $coalition_select = $_POST['coalition_select'];
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style = "display: inline-block;">
        <!-- the users -->
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Candidates</option>
            <?php 
                include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM candidates WHERE coalition = '$coalition_select'");
                while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['username'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I looked at few examples dealing with a similar situation with no success. The two menus function just fine separately so the issue is not with the connection. Please note that I wish for this action to takes place without any button being pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As php is server side code, you can't get the 1st dropdown's selected value in php part (for the 2nd dropdown).

To fill the 2nd dropdown based on 1st dropdown's selection, you need to use ajax.

Do a ajax call on "change" event of 1st dropdown ie Coalitions and ajax url should return you the list of candidates based on ajax parameter ( Coalitions selected value). Once you get the ajax response them you can fill those values in "Candidates" dropdown using JS/Jquery.

Here are the sample code which should fulfill your requirement:

> > $( "#coalition_id" ).change(function() {
> >
> > var selected_id = $(this).val();
> >
> > // path of the file which should return list of candidates (JSON
> >     format ) for "coalition" value passed to this url via GET method
> >
> > var url = "path/to/candidates_file.php?coalition=" + selected_id;
> >
> > // ajax call
> >
> > $.get(, function(json, status){
> >            $('#candidatesselect').empty();
> >
> > // loop through each value & fill the candidates dropdown
> >
> > $.each(json, function(i, item) {
> >
> > $('#candidatesselect').append(
> >             $('', {
> >                 value: item.owner,
> >                 text: item.username
> >             }, ''));
> >
> > });
> >
> > });
> >
> > });

Comment: Thanks for the answer what if I want to delete the said candidate. is it not possible to populate the second list using php?

Comment: on which event/action you want to delete the candidate? whenever you delete the candidate, you can do a ajax call to get the new list of candidates